# Else clause in a python list comprehension with two loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

So I have a nested dict of list called **dict1** as follows:

```
{"types": [{"name": "Chinese", 
            "sub": 
                [{
                  "menu": [{"name": "Ya", "cost": 1}, {"name": "Ja", "cost": 2}], 
                  "name": "Soups"
                 }, 
                 {
                  "menu": [{"name": "Ta", "cost": 3}, {"name": "Ba", "cost": 4}], 
                  "name": "Mains"
                }]
           },
           {"name": "Indian(Mains)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Sa", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Pa", "cost": 6}]
           }
         ]
}
```

What I finally need is :

```
{"types": [{"name": "Chinese(Soups)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Ya", "cost": 1}, {"name": "Ja", "cost": 2}]},

           {"name": "Chinese(Mains)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Ta", "cost": 3}, {"name": "Ba", "cost": 4}]},

           {"name": "Indian(Mains)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Sa", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Pa", "cost": 6}]}
          ]
}
```

So in summary, if the inner dict contains the **sub** key, separate it into individual dicts else leave it as it is. For reasons best known to me, I am using list comprehensions to this.This is what I have till now :

```
dict1['types'] = [{'name': '%s(%s)' % (outer['name'], inner['name']),
                   'menu': inner['menu']}
                   for outer in dict1['types']
                   if 'sub' in outer 
                   for inner in outer['sub']]
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{"types": [{"name": "Chinese(Soups)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Ya", "cost": 1}, {"name": "Ja", "cost": 2}]},

           {"name": "Chinese(Mains)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Ta", "cost": 3}, {"name": "Ba", "cost": 4}]}
          ]
}
```

As is evident,it gives me only 2 dicts and not 3 which is obvious since I don't have an **else** clause. My question is how do I use the **else** clause in a list comprehension with two loops in this scenario ?

**EDIT**
As Martijn mentioned in the comments, this is not possible with list comprehension,I am ok with other ways of accomplishing this as well by modifying the existing dict

Comment: `if` in a list comprehension loop can only *filter* (exclude) items. There is no `else` option, because including an item is the default.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters..could you please then let me know what is the best way of accomplishing this without creating a new dict and modifying the existing dict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a list comprehension loop, `if` only lets you filter items you iterate over, not swap out further loops. Because `if` acts as a filter, there is no `else` as the default action in to *include* the iterated element.

You'd have to use an expression in your inner loop to pick one of two alternatives for the `for` loop to iterate over:

```
[{'name': '%s(%s)' % (outer['name'], inner['name']), 'menu': inner['menu']} if 'sub' in outer else inner
 for outer in dict1['types']
 for inner in (outer['sub'] if 'sub' in outer else [outer])]
```

So this picks either the `outer['sub']` list, or the list `[outer]` to iterate over for the `inner` name. You then use a conditional expression to generate a new dictionary, or simply re-use `inner` (which is really `outer`) if no `'sub'` key is present in `outer`.

Of course, you can simplify that by using `dict.get()`:

```
[{'name': '%s(%s)' % (outer['name'], inner['name']), 'menu': inner['menu']} if 'sub' in outer else inner
 for outer in dict1['types']
 for inner in outer.get('sub', [outer])]
```

Demo:

```
>>> dict1 = {"types": [{"name": "Chinese",
...             "sub":
...                 [{
...                   "menu": [{"name": "Ya", "cost": 1}, {"name": "Ja", "cost": 2}],
...                   "name": "Soups"
...                  },
...                  {
...                   "menu": [{"name": "Ta", "cost": 3}, {"name": "Ba", "cost": 4}],
...                   "name": "Mains"
...                 }]
...            },
...            {"name": "Indian(Mains)",
...             "menu": [{"name": "Sa", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Pa", "cost": 6}]
...            }
...          ]
... }
>>> [{'name': '%s(%s)' % (outer['name'], inner['name']), 'menu': inner['menu']} if 'sub' in outer else inner
...  for outer in dict1['types']
...  for inner in outer.get('sub', [outer])]
[{'name': 'Chinese(Soups)', 'menu': [{'name': 'Ya', 'cost': 1}, {'name': 'Ja', 'cost': 2}]}, {'name': 'Chinese(Mains)', 'menu': [{'name': 'Ta', 'cost': 3}, {'name': 'Ba', 'cost': 4}]}, {'name': 'Indian(Mains)', 'menu': [{'name': 'Sa', 'cost': 5}, {'name': 'Pa', 'cost': 6}]}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[{'menu': [{'cost': 1, 'name': 'Ya'}, {'cost': 2, 'name': 'Ja'}],
  'name': 'Chinese(Soups)'},
 {'menu': [{'cost': 3, 'name': 'Ta'}, {'cost': 4, 'name': 'Ba'}],
  'name': 'Chinese(Mains)'},
 {'menu': [{'cost': 5, 'name': 'Sa'}, {'cost': 6, 'name': 'Pa'}],
  'name': 'Indian(Mains)'}]
```

Personally, I'd use a generator function here, rather than a single list comprehension:

```
def flattened_menu(types):
    for entry in types:
        if 'sub' in entry:
            # flatten out nested menu entries
            for subentry in entry['sub']:
                yield {
                    'name': '{0[name]}({1[name]})'.format(entry, subentry),
                    'menu': subentry['menu']}
        else:
            yield entry

dict1['types'] = list(flattened_menu(dict1['types']))
```

Comment: just to understand..is there a better way without using list comprehension ?

Comment: @Amistad: I've added an alternative; don't be afraid of using a more verbose function here, it makes it much easier to figure out later on what the code does.